# ngResource does not pass parameters - how to debug?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, angular-resource

I have the following resource definition:

```
myservices.factory('User', ['$resource',
    function($resource){
        return $resource('/user/:screenName', {}, {
            whoami: {
                url: '/user',
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false,
                params: {
                    op: 'whoami'
                }
            },
            query: {
                url: '/user',
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            },
            update: {
                method:'GET',
                params: {
                    op: 'update'
                },
                isArray: false,
            },
            delete: {
                method:'GET',
                params: {
                    op: 'delete'
                },
                isArray: false,
            }

        });
    }]);
```

and I was thinking it will pass `screenName` as the part of URL. Unfortunately, this does not happen.

The controller code is follows:

```
            var user = new User();
            user.firstname = $scope.selectedUser.firstName;
            user.lastname = $scope.selectedUser.lastName;
            user.screenName = $scope.selectedUser.screenName;
            user.password1 = $scope.selectedUser.password1;
            user.password2 = $scope.selectedUser.password2;
            user.roles = $scope.selectedUser.roles;
            user.maximalCalories = $scope.selectedUser.maximalCalories;

            user.$update();
```

Actually it passes:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/user?op=update HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
...
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
...
Referer: http://localhost:8080/app/index.html
```

i.e. it passes neither parameters except explicit one.

**UDPATE**

If I do

```
    User.$update(
                {
                    firstname : $scope.selectedUser.firstName,
                    lastname : $scope.selectedUser.lastName,
                    screenName : $scope.selectedUser.screenName,
                    password1 : $scope.selectedUser.password1,
                    password2 : $scope.selectedUser.password2,
                    roles : $scope.selectedUser.roles,
                    maximalCalories : $scope.selectedUser.maximalCalories,
                }
            );
```

I get an exception `TypeError: User.$update is not a function`

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently, Angular adds function `$update` to the object and function `update` to the class, and if I have object at `LHS`, it will pass only by POST...

Comment: Could you look at developer console network tab..look at the request body..it must have passed object in body..

Comment: Of course, because you are not passing `screenName` to resource call.

Comment: @dfsq shouldn't it take it from the object `user`?

Comment: @PankajParkar it doesn't. I see request in fiddler, there is no body, it is GET request.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing `screenName` to resource. Should be:

```
user.$update({screenName: $scope.selectedUser.screenName});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have wrong request type for you `$resource`'s `udpate` object, It should have method `PUT` instead of `GET`

```
update: {
    method: 'PUT', //<--change it 'PUT' from 'GET'
    params: {
        op: 'update'
    },
    isArray: false,
},
```

Also you had wrong type for delete method, it should have `method: 'DELETE'` instead of `method: 'GET'`

Comment: Yes I know I can redesign serverside, but what if I couldn't?

Comment: @Dims I'm not talking at all about serverside..I just said to change the `$resource` object..

Comment: @Dims could you try what I suggested?